# How to detect when a Fake Element has been removed in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a custom plugin for CKEditor, it adds a button on the toolbar and when users click on it i create a div with a specific ID and show up a "fake element" with an icon. That's all i need and it works.

I needed to limit that funcionality to once for each article. So i created a Javascript variable that increase every time my user click the button, and disable the button after the first click.

But i need to know when users remove the **fake element** to decrease my variable, enable the button again and let him add another one

Does anyone knows how to detect when a fake element has been removed?

Comment: you could just set `var fake_element_set = true` and check for that, but if someone's knowledgeable enough to fiddle with the dom to remove the element, they're probabyl knowledgeable enough to just set that var back to false. Since anything you try would have to be done client-side, you'll essentially have ZERO chance of this working properly. you have to assume everything/anything you do can be undone by the user, because you're in their house.

Comment: That's not my point. Imagine that we are using a CKEditor plugin that let's me insert an image in a textarea, i add an image and then i retract and remove it (via backspace keyboard). No way to detect that action? in this case i need to detect if users removes the icon that i added has a fake element

Comment: sure, but you'd probably have to scan the contents of the textarea on every keyup/toolbar click to see if your element is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holding a state variable is not a good idea here, you'll have to check the content anyway, when the content is reopened to update existing content.

You could look for objects containing the `data-cke-real-element-type` attribute (note you need to provide the `realElementType` parameter to the [`createFakeElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-createFakeElement) method). E.g. with that you can easily find the number of anchor fake elements in the editable just by calling:

```
editor.editable().find( '*[data-cke-real-element-type="anchor"]' ).count();
```

Of course you need to replace `"anchor"` with your name registered as the `realElementType` parameter.

Then all you need to do is hook checking to proper [editor events](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor).